# keycloak-connect refresh tokens early

Tags: java, node.js, keycloak, kong

I am using Keycloak to authenticate users in a node application.
This node application makes further requests to a Java backend (using KONG) which are authenticated using the same token as I receive.

My problem is now that I have glitches, whenever the token is close to be expired.

Example:
Token expires at *2020-12-11T05:36:40.805Z*

But it is currently *2020-12-11T05:36:40.700Z* (105ms before the token expires)

Between the time of my token validation and the request hitting the Java server, the token is already expired. On top of that, it could be that the Java server's clock is a few ms ahead.

I am trying to configure some kind of grace period or force a token refresh already 5 seconds before it expires - but I can find zero information about it.

I went through the keycloak-connect source code and cannot find any method that would help me any further here.

Am I on the wrong track? I mean there must be more people struggling with that, no?

Help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: I vaguely remember there was a property named `timeSkew` of the main `Keycloak` config  which handles the local clock deltas. Check the [Keycloak JS docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#javascript-adapter-reference) and see if it can be applied to your Node.js app.